# How can I use textcat with Python?

Tags: python, pip

I would like to give [TextCat](http://odur.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/) a try. It would be most convenient for me if I could run it from Python, as I would like to see how well it does on a private dataset.

I gave [languagedet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/languagedet/0.1.1), but according to

```
from languagedet.mixed import MixedDetector
det = MixedDetector()
print(det.available)
```

much less than the 69 languages claimed on TextCats website are available via languagedet.

I also tried [pylibtextcat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibtextcat/0.2), but I get:

```
Collecting pylibtextcat
  Using cached pylibtextcat-0.2.tar.bz2
Building wheels for collected packages: pylibtextcat
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pylibtextcat ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1dkslney/pylibtextcat/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpyct9pyfepip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'textcat' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DVERSION="0.2" -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c libtextcat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/libtextcat.o -Wall -Wextra
  libtextcat.c:7:32: fatal error: libtextcat/textcat.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pylibtextcat
  Running setup.py clean for pylibtextcat
Failed to build pylibtextcat
Installing collected packages: pylibtextcat
  Running setup.py install for pylibtextcat ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1dkslney/pylibtextcat/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lwxglu50-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'textcat' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DVERSION="0.2" -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c libtextcat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/libtextcat.o -Wall -Wextra
    libtextcat.c:7:32: fatal error: libtextcat/textcat.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1dkslney/pylibtextcat/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lwxglu50-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1dkslney/pylibtextcat/
```

when I try to install it (and I have `libexttextcat-2.0-0`, `libexttextcat-data`, `libexttextcat-dev` installed).

Can I use TextCat with Python?

Comment: I just saw http://thomas.mangin.com//content/texcat-in-python.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems not to be the same, but nltk has:

```
from nltk.classify import textcat

text = "This is a simple example."
cls = textcat.TextCat()

distances = cls.lang_dists(text)  # a dict of 437 elements
cls.guess_language(text)  # a str
```

Comment: This is really slow if you pass a big amount of data. I wonder if this is possible to do Textcat('eng') which then will test against one language and not all of them. I will just use a subset of the data to guess then